# What's wrong with Blazor's InputCheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to realize Blazor's InputCheckBox with Dictionary<string, bool> model. In fact I want to realize a set of CheckBoxes in foreach cycle. And while I have at the first line of the cycle  property with {get; set;} in InputCheckBox (as shown in my [Visual Studio's screenchort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGNfP.png)) it turns to readonly property with only {get;}

```
@page "/select-props"
@{
    CsvContent headers = new();
    
}
<h3>Properties picker</h3>

<div class="container container-fluid overflow-auto">
    <table class="table overflow-auto">
        <EditForm Model="headers">
            @foreach (var item in headers.Headers)
            {
            <tr class="row ">
                @if (item.Key is not null)
                    {
                        <td scope="col" class="col border border-1 border-secondary">
                            <InputCheckbox class="btn-check" @bind-Value="item.Value">
                                @item.Key
                            </InputCheckbox>
                        </td>
                    }
            </tr>
            }
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </EditForm>
    </table>
</div>

@code {
}
```

That is the model class:

```
    public class CsvContent
    {
        static Dictionary<int, char> divider = new() { { 0, ',' }, { 1, ';' }, { 2, '\t' } };
        public static List<List<string>?> FileContent { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool>? Headers { get; set; }

        public static async Task/*<List<List<string>>*/  ReadCsvAsync(string path, int divederCode = 2)
        {
            FileContent = new List<List<string>?>();
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
            {
                string? line;
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    List<string> cells = new();
                    cells.AddRange(line.Split(divider[divederCode]));
                    FileContent.Add(cells);
                }
            }
        }

        public CsvContent()
        {
            if (FileContent is not null)
            {
                foreach (var item in FileContent)
                    Headers.TryAdd(item.ElementAt(0), false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't relize why my dictionary value turn to readonly, please help...

Comment: Why do you think your dictionary value is not settable?  What, exactly, happens?

Comment: It has no relationship with InputCheckBox at all,KeyValuePair.Value is readonly itself

Comment: @RuikaiFeng It looks like you are right, though Chat GPT considers diffirent way: Yes, you can use a Dictionary<string, bool> model in Blazor's inputcheckbox. You can bind the value of the checkbox to the boolean value in the dictionary and use the key of the dictionary as the label for the checkbox. :-)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Zufar - ChatGPT is just a parrot regurgitating (old and stale) data.   Garbage in, garbage out!

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for binding to Dictionary<string, bool>:

```
@foreach (var item in headers.Headers)
{
    bool boolVal = headers.Headers[item.Key];
    ...
    <InputCheckbox Value="boolVal" ValueExpression="@(() => boolVal)" ValueChanged="@(b => headers.Headers[item.Key] = b)">
                        @item.Key
    </InputCheckbox>
    ...
}
```

It work in ASP.Net 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyValuePair.Value` is readonly, there is not much you can do about it. However, I believe you can bind it going through the dictionary directly:

`@bind-Value="headers.Headers[item.Key]"`.

Answer (score 0):

As eluded to in the other answer and comments, `KeyValuePair` objects are *readonly* .

You can move away from the Dictionary, and use a `List` of a header state object.  You are almost certainly doing this in the context of some sort of Grid control, so will be using the Header State elsewhere.

Here's a Demo page with the object classes included in the page.

Note the null reference warning goes away by removing the nullable `?` in the declaration and declaring a default value for `Headers`.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<h3>Properties picker</h3>

<EditForm Model="headers">
    @foreach (var item in headers.Headers)
    {
        <div class="form-check mb-2">
            <InputCheckbox class="form-check-input" @bind-Value=item.State />
            <label class="form-check-label">@item.Name</label>
        </div>
    }
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    @foreach (var item in headers.Headers)
    {
        <pre>@item.Name : @item.State</pre>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private Model headers = new();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        headers.Headers.Add(new("UK", false));
        headers.Headers.Add(new("France", false));
        headers.Headers.Add(new("Spain", false));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        // The null reference error goes away by declaring a default value for Headers
        public List<HeaderData> Headers { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class HeaderData
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public bool State { get; set; }

        public HeaderData(string name, bool state = false)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.State = state;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]